# Can codecvt_utf8_utf16 be used with wfstream?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, utf-8, fstream, utf-16

I saw this on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16):

> This is an N:M conversion facet, and cannot be used with std::basic_filebuf (which only permits 1:N conversions, such as UTF-32/UTF-8, between the internal and the external encodings).

Does this mean I can't use codecvt_utf8_utf16 with fstream to R/W a utf8 file and code like the following is invalid?

```cpp
std::wifstream f("demo.txt");
f.imbue(std::locale(f.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>));
std::wstring test;
f >> test;
```

And what is "N:M conversion facet"?

Comment: Don't use it, it is deprecated for a good reason.

Comment: N:M meaning there's variable-length encoding on both sides. Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 are variable length. Actual implementations of fstream may actually work with this facet as an extension (GNU libstdc++ works in my experience), but it's not generally guaranteed.